# Modify list items in Ansible / Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, ansible

For instance you have a list variable in your role...

```
myitems:
  - one
  - two
```

... and want to modify each item within Ansible (e.g. append a string before/after), you can...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

... do the trick by creating following two variables in your Role's `vars/main.yml` file (or at every other place where vars could be defined):

```
interim_string: "{% for item in myitems %}with-{{item}}X {% endfor %}"
result_list: "{{ interim_string.split() }}"
```

The resulting `result_list` now contains following values:

```
- with-oneX
- with-twoX
```

Mention the whitespace after the `x` when defining `interim_string`. It is used for splitting the `interim_string` into a list again. You can split by another char or sequence (e.g. `split('#')`). However this would result in an empty list item at the end of the `result_list`.

Answer (score 12):

Nowadays the best idiom for this is probably to combine Ansible's map filter with its [regex_replace](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) filter. For example, to append `-bar` to each item in a list:

```
myitems:
- one
- two
result_list: "{{ myitems | map('regex_replace', '$', '-bar') | list }}"
```

Which would produce:

```
result_list:
- one-bar
- two-bar
```

---

Or to prepend `foo-` to each item a list:

```
myitems:
- one
- two
result_list: "{{ myitems | map('regex_replace', '^', 'foo-') | list }}"
```

Which would produce:

```
result_list:
- foo-one
- foo-two
```

---

Or to wrap each item in a list with `foo-` and `-bar`:

```
myitems:
- one
- two
result_list: "{{ myitems | map('regex_replace', '(.+)', 'foo-\\1-bar') | list }}"
```

Which would produce:

```
result_list:
- foo-one-bar
- foo-two-bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way I found to achieve similar result:

```
{{ ansible_play_hosts | zip_longest([], fillvalue=':2181')| map('join') | join(',') }}
```

Looks ugly, but given `ansible_play_hosts=['a', 'b']` it produces `a:2181,b:2181`